# CefNet DllNotFoundException on Linux

Tags: linux, chromium-embedded, .so, avaloniaui

I implemented the webview from the [CefNet](https://github.com/CefNet/CefNet) package on Windows and it works fine. Now that I moved to implementing it on Linux (Ubuntu), the `NativeMethods.dlopen` method in the initialization process always throws the `DllNotFoundException` error. The only mentioning of the error I [found](https://github.com/CefNet/CefNet/discussions/45) was answered that the major and minor versions of the CefNet package and the CEF build must match, which they absolutely do in my case: CefNet version 105.3.22248.142 and CEF-Linux64 version 105.3.39, and the path to the cef is evaluated correctly, so I don't really get it what else could be the problem

Comment: Please add the complete exception stack trace of the `DllNotFoundException` you have mentioned. This will help to understand the cause better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at CefNet source code, and found the `dlopen` P/Invoke declaration potentially causing the problem:

https://github.com/CefNet/CefNet/blob/85bfe1c0b81e3f5a060d456bbff66e47fda0d493/CefNet/Unsafe/NativeMethods.cs#L34

```
    [DllImport("libdl", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern IntPtr dlopen(string path, int mode);
```

As I can understand, the `libdl.so` may appear to be missing in your Linux environment. We have recently resolved the similar problem when implementing Linux support in [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) (this is a commercial competitor to the solutions like CefNet). You can either replace the library name to `libdl.so.2` in the CefNet source code and rebuild it locally, or try making a symlink in the operating system that redirects from `libdl.so` to `libdl.so.2`. After that, the `DllNotFoundException` should be gone.